# Doubt with an isomorphism of $Hom(K,V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

Let $V$ vector spaces. Prove $Hom(\mathbb{K},V)$ is isomorphic to $V$

I find a hint for this exercise:

Consider $\varphi\colon\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{K},V)\to V$ defined by linear form  $f\colon\mathbb{K}\to V$, by $\varphi (f)=f(1)$

We need to show $\varphi$ is biyective.

**For injectivity:**

Suppose $\varphi (f)=\varphi (g)$  then $f(1)=g(1)$ this implies $f=g$.

In consequence $\varphi$ is injective.

**For surjectivity:**

Let $u\in V$ and $f\in Hom(\mathbb{K},V)$ then $\varphi(f)=f(1)=f(1.u)=1f(u)=f(u)=u$

**I dont know it is the correct form of prove this. Can someone help me? (Is a little confused to me the injectivity and surjectivity of functions in dual spaces.)**

Comment: Why does $f(1)=g(1)$ imply $f=g$? Two functions are equal if they are equal for every point in the domain, not just one point in the domain.

Comment: @ziggurism, but $\varphi (f)=f(1)$ for all $f,g$ always, send to $f(1),g(1)$

Comment: I can't understand your comment, but if you want to conclude that $f=g$, then you must first show that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$ in the domain. For example, notice that if $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2$, then $f(1)=g(1)$, but $f\neq g$. Why are your functions different?

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote for surjectivity doesn't make a lot of sense. For instance, $f(u)$ is meaningless, since $f$ is supposed to evaluate on scalars.

Given $u\in V$, you define $f\in \text{Hom}\,(\mathbb K,V)$ by $f(\lambda)=\lambda u$. Then 
$$
\varphi(f)=f(1)=u. 
$$
So $\varphi$ is surjective.

Comment: Thanks martin. I was very stuck in that part. Thanks a lot!  With the injectivity, is okay?

Comment: It is, but you wrote little enough that it is not clear if you know what you are doing. Formally you should have written $f(\lambda)=\lambda f(1)=\lambda g(1)=g(\lambda)$. If that's clear to you, the proof is ok.

Comment: Martin, a little question, if $\lambda=1$ then $\varphi(f)=f(1)=u$ no?

Comment: No. What would the relation between $\lambda$ and $\varphi$ and $f$?

Comment: $f$ is a linear form, define $f\colon\mathbb{K}\to V$  , $\varphi$ is the function such that $\varphi (f)=f(1)$ and $\varphi \in \mathbb{K}$.

Comment: Exactly. So, what does "if $\lambda=1$ have to do with it?

Comment: Of course,i say that because if $f(\lambda)=\lambda u$ and $\lambda=1$ then $f(1)=(1)(u)=u$  and then $\varphi(f)=f(1)=u.$

Comment: Now I see what you meant. Yes.